# SKSpritenode array display

Tags: arrays, swift, sprite-kit

I have **5** `SKSpriteNode`, that are displayed in `didMove(to view)`:

```
cyan = self.childNode(withName: "cyan") as! SKSpriteNode
    red = self.childNode(withName: "red") as! SKSpriteNode
    green = self.childNode(withName: "green") as! SKSpriteNode
    yellow = self.childNode(withName: "yellow") as! SKSpriteNode
    purple = self.childNode(withName: "purple") as! SKSpriteNode
```

I made an array and added them to the array:

```
        colors = [cyan, red, green, yellow, purple]
```

I shuffled the array so now the order is different and I want to display the colors again in the order of the array, how can I do that?
I searched the web but could not find anything useful.

Comment: You want to show the sprites from left to right using the new orders of the `colors` array?

Comment: yes, I'm trying to display it from 0 - 4, maybe I wasn't clear enough, the colors are sprite kit nodes.

Answer (score 2):

You can spawn several sprites on the screen assigning to them a different `x` coordinate.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    func spawn(sprites: [SKSpriteNode]) {
        for (index, sprite) in sprites.enumerated() {
            sprite.position.x = frame.width / CGFloat(sprites.count) * CGFloat(index) - (frame.width / 2)
        }
    }
}
```

Now just call `spawn` passing as parameter the array of sprites.

Comment: Thanks, It is not excatly what I meant, but I'm trying a solution now.

Comment: @swiftnewbie instead of saying "not exactly what I meant." I suggest you describe in detail what you're trying to achieve. appzYourLife's answer is what I thought you wanted when I read your question.

Comment: @0x141E sorry for being unclear. I have an array of sprites, each sprite has it's color, so the array is colors, if the first value in the array is 'red' I want to display the red sprite first and so on. I tried to do a for loop that runs on the array and have this code: sprite.texutre = self.childnode(with name: sprite.name) but it does not work. the sprite.name is the name of the sprite in the .sks file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the colors in the order of the shuffled array, you can loop on the colors array:

```
for color in colors {
    //do whatever you want with the color
}
```

Comment: I tired this before creating the question, but it does not work, as it is a sprite kit node. sorry for begin unclear.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to display? The literal name of the color of the node or the name of the node?

Comment: I have a variable called red (for example), this variable is a SpriteKit node. if the color in colors is red, I want to display the red image.

Comment: I'm not sure why the for loop wouldn't work just because it's a SKSpriteNode. Is it just not coming up in the right order using the loop?

Comment: well, I does work, I am now thinking of a solution how to change the texture. I will edit the question if I won't succeed.